# Передача выбранного элемента в select

Tags: html, select

Есть форма заказа:

```
<form method="post" action="../bin/balans_zakaz.php" name="balans"> 
    <select class="form-control" id="first" name="operator" style="width: 355px;" onChange="$('.operators-time').hide(); $('#' + this.value).show();">
                        <option value="0">Выберите оператора</option>
                        <option value="Iridium">Iridium</option>
                        <option value="Thuraya">Thuraya</option>
                        <option value="Globalstar">Globalstar</option>
                        <option value="Inmarsat">Inmarsat</option>
    </select>
```

Исходя из выбранного option, появляется соотвествующий следующий вариант, например:

```
<select class="form-control operators-time" id="Iridium" style="width: 355px;display:none;">
                    <option value="75">75 мин (199$)</option>
                    <option value="200">200 мин (559$)</option>
                    <option value="500">500 мин (851$)</option>
                    <option value="1000">1000 мин (1605$)</option>
                    <option value="3000">3000 мин (4777$)</option>
                    <option value="5000">5000 мин (7979$)</option>
</select>
```

Передачу первого селекта сделал так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        selectList = document.forms["balans"].elements["operator"];
        selectedIndex = selectList.selectedIndex;
        value = selectList.options[selectedIndex].value;
        text = selectList.options[selectedIndex].text;
</script>
```

Как передавать второй селект?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так делать не совсем комильфо. Я бы рекомендовал вам сделать связанные списки с помощью AJAX. Это будет красивее и быстрее работать, т.к. вы снизите кол-во запросов при первой загрузке страницы.
Вот вариант реализации таких select'ов:

http://webersoft.ru/select-ajax-mysql/